# Erro ao fechar o Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: java, android

Eu visualizo uma imagem com Intent.ACTION_VIEW e ao fechar ocorre o seguinte erro, estou achando que é em MainActivity.class:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium, PID: 9168
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium/com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.Fragments.AlterarOsFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                   Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.Fragments.AlterarOsFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:446)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:108)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2058)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:328)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:88)
                      at com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.Fragments.AlterarOsFragment has no zero argument constructor
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1641)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:435)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:108) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2058) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:328) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:88) 
                      at com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
                      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
                      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1639)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:435) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:108) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:2058) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:328) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:88) 
                      at com.emerson.barcellos.mgordenservicopremium.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Meu Fragment.class

```
...
Intent inte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        inte.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri.toString()), "*/*");
                        startActivity(inte);
...
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    View headerView;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    private int id;
    private int RESULT_BARCODE = 3;
    public static DataBaseHandler db;
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        db = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(this);


/**
 Cursor cursor = db.Select(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
 int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID);
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 do {
 values.clear();
 values.put(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID_SEQUENCIA, cursor.getString(index0));
 db.Update(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS, values, DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_ID + "=?", new String[]{cursor.getString(index0)});
 Log.v("aviso", cursor.getString(index0));
 }
 while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }**/

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                selectedMenu();
            }
        };
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (bundle != null) {
            int numero = bundle.getInt("numero");
            if (numero != 0) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "home").addToBackStack("tag_back").commit();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new AlterarOsFragment(bundle.getInt("numero")), "os").addToBackStack("tag_back").commit();

            } else {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "home").commit();
            }

        } else {
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "home").commit();
        }

        perfil();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        id = item.getItemId();
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    void selectedMenu() {
        Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            if (!currentFragment.getTag().equals("home")) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "home");
                ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_abrir) {
           // if (Funcoes.idUltimOs()) {
           //     Funcoes.popUpPremium();
           // } else {
                Intent intentA = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AbrirOsActivity.class);
                intentA.putExtra("edit", false);
                intentA.putExtra("numero", 1);
                startActivity(intentA);
                finish();
           // }

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_alterar) {
            new Os(MainActivity.this, 0).popUpIdOs(getSupportFragmentManager());
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pesuisar) {
            if (!currentFragment.getTag().equals("pesquisar")) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new OsListFragment(null, null, false), "pesquisar");
                ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_scanner) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BarcodeScanner.class);
            intent.putExtra("tipo", true);
            intent.putExtra("edit", false);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_BARCODE);
            //  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            //  values.put(DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_GRUPO, "9y8FwQTy");

            // db.Update(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS, values, null, null);
            //new AtualizaServerToLocal(getBaseContext(), 1, 2).execute();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_clientes) {
            if (!currentFragment.getTag().equals("clientes")) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new ClientesFragment(), "clientes");
                ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
        /**else if (id == R.id.nav_grupos) {
         if (!currentFragment.getTag().equals("grupos")) {
         ft.replace(R.id.container, new ChartFragment(), "grupos");
         ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
         ft.commit();
         }
         } **/
        else if (id == R.id.nav_cadastro) {
            if (!currentFragment.getTag().equals("cadastro")) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new CadastrosFragment(1), "cadastro");
                ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_financeiro) {
            if (!currentFragment.getTag().equals("financeiro")) {
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new FinanceiroFragment(), "financeiro");
                ft.addToBackStack("tag_back");
                ft.commit();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_configuracao) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConfiguracaoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // this.finish();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_BARCODE) {
                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, new OsListFragment(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_OS + "." + DataBaseHandler.KEY_OS_BARCODE, contents, false), "pesquisa").addToBackStack("tag_back").commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void perfil() {
        Cursor c = db.Select(DataBaseHandler.TABLE_USER, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            int iNome = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_USER_NAME);
            int iEmpresa = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_USER_EMPRESA);
            int iFoto = c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_USER_FOTO);
            byte[] ft = c.getBlob(iFoto);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (ft != null) {

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ft, 0, ft.length);

            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_emotion_24dp);
            }

            setUserData(c.getString(iNome), c.getString(iEmpresa), bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void setUserData(String user, String email, Bitmap avatar) {
        ((TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserEmail)).setText(email);
        ((TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername)).setText(user);
        if (avatar != null)
            ((ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar)).setImageDrawable(new RoundImage(avatar));
    }

}
```

Comment: Pode publicar o código completo do seu AlterarOsFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo erro que deu, sua classe AlterarOsFragment não parece ter um construtor vazio, que é obrigatório para Fragments. E estou percebendo que você tenta inicializar essa classe passando um valor no construtor.

Nesse post, tem a forma correta de inicializar um Fragment passando um valor para o mesmo sem necessariamente ser pelo construtor da classe. Eu utilizo sempre este método:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor

Comment: Obrigado @Márcio Oliveira, funcionou pra mim. esse bug estava tirando meu sono. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: fiz conforme me indicou no link `public static AlterarOsFragment newInstance(int numero) {
        AlterarOsFragment f = new AlterarOsFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(2);
        bdl.putInt(EXTRA_NUMERO, numero);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.numeroOs = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_NUMERO);
    }` eu uso um menu drawer ,não dá mais erro mas sempre me leva ao Fragment defalut, você sabe porque isso ocorre?

Comment: Coloca breakpoints no código e vai debugando para entender por onde o app está percorrendo no código.